# Hang on boot when enabling camera on Model 1 A

Tags: camera, raspicam

When trying to enable the camera on an old, first-generation RPi, with the latest Lite image, you get the following message from raspistill:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM) mmal: 
mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1) mmal: Failed to create 
camera component mmal: main: Failed to create camera component mmal: Camera is not enabled in this 
build. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "camera" has been enabled
```

okay, great. now you run sudo raspi-config, enable camera under interfaces, and reboot.

Now boot hangs and the board doesn't connect to ethernet.

Comment: Check the memory options in `config.txt`, AFAIK you need to allocate more memory to the GPU if you're using the camera.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be related to the line that raspi-config inserts into config.txt,

gpu_mem=128

Remove the SD card, put into another computer, remove this line. The camera now works.